# How do I create an entity reference from a webform submission?

Tags: 8, nodes, webforms

I have two content types : Parents and students. each content type has a entity reference to the other content type. I am using module : [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and [webform creator](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_content_creator) to create the content.

Once a parent is login s/he can add a student by calling the student form.
After filling up the student form and submitting it the parent is redirected to the parent page which should show the student(s) just created.

How can I create the **relation parent-student** (one to many) so that each added student show on the page of the parent that created him/her once the webform is submitted or just by going to a parent page ?

Do I use token or how can I programmatically create the relation on webform submit?

Note: I tried unsuccessfully using the entity select in webform to link the student to parent since it is the current user (the creator of student). The entity reference generated is anonymous instead of the parent (the creator of student).

Comment: Maybe try inline entity forms instead. But generally speaking you need to add another submit handler to your webform via hook_form_alter in a custom module. Have you done that already?

Comment: I tried unsuccessfully using the entity select in webform to link the student to parent since it is the current user (the creator of student). Sorry I am a newbie and have little knowledge in coding. the entity reference generated is anonymous instead of the parent (the creator of student).

Comment: looks like a view is what I need : https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-user-content/